Беглый гласный и мягкий знак
The following words have all the same grammatical classification (тип склонения 5*б по классификации А. А. Зализняка): огурец (gén. огурца), отец (gén. отца),  конец (gén. конца),  жилец (gén. жильца). Nevertheless, in some cases the consonant remains soft and a ь appears, and in other cases the consonant becomes hard and there is no ь. Is there a general rule?

Yes, there is a rule. As Zaliznyak's Grammatical Dictionary itself states, the soft sign (ь) appears:

in м (мо) 6* nouns: у́­лей — у́­лья, солове́й — соловья́;
in м (мо) 3* nouns: зве­рёк — зве­рь­ка́, unless the fleeting vowel is preceded by ш, ж, ч, ш or ц: горшо́к — горшка́;
when the fleeting vowel е/ё is preceded by л: лёд — льда, па́лец — па́льца.


Sergey's answer is spot on. I'll just clarify why it is that only л gets the special treatment and receives a soft sign before the sibilants:

In Old Russian, when the orthography rules were being established, all the sibilants used to be soft. That's why we write и after ш, ж.
Up until very recently (mid-XX century), in consonant clusters, initial consonants matched the palatalizaton of the last consonant, except for л.

The latter rule still holds for some consonant clusters: words like кончик, мясник are pronounced like коньчик, мясьник almost universally; many (but not all) speakers soften м, к, г, х in words like ромбик, пикник, глина, хлипкий; on the classic stage and, before the 1950s, also on radio and TV, there was a requirement to soften all consonants that were not an л, preceding a soft one. Words like спринт, стрелец, впредь etc. had to be pronounced сьпьринт, сьтьрелец, вьпьредь.
This rule worked in Old Russian and early Modern Russian, so reflecting the softness of non-final consonants in consonant clusters, except for л,  was unnecessary, and the soft sign was omitted.
Before the Russian orthography had been codified, there were frequent deviations in both ways: the lack of the soft sign after л: колца, стрелцы and the presence of the soft sign in the consonant clusters: старьцы, гостиньцы and so on.

It is a very interesting complementary answer, thank you very much! "Before the Russian orthography had been codified": are you evoking the 1918 reform or something older?

@Bruno: the first thorough codification was Grot's Русское правописание, first published in 1885.
